# javascript variable is not showing correct value

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have this ajax call function.

```
function saveData(ip)
{

    $JQ.ajax({

     type: "POST",

     url: "all_actions.php",

     data: 
     {
         page_url:document.URL,
         ip_address:ip 
     },

     success: function(responce)
     {

         if(responce)
         {
             var newtoken;
             newtoken=responce;
             return newtoken;
         }
     }
    });
}
```

Then i have another function

```
 function getToken()
{
    var ip=myip
    var mytoken;
    mytoken=saveData(ip);
    alert(mytoken);

}
```

My token giving undefined in alert.Although if i alert newtoken variable in savedata response it gives correct value in alert box.why if i return that avlue it does not assigned to mytoken.

is it something time delay issue.??

Need your help...

Comment: AJAX = **Asynchronous** Javascript And XML. There are many questions with the same problem here on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return from an `asynchronous` call.

You have to consume the return data inside the `success` function. Whatever you are going to do with `token`, write that code inside the `success` handler.

```
success: function(responce)
 {

     if(responce)
     {
         var newtoken;
         newtoken=responce;

         // Global variable
         sourceid = newtoken;

         return newtoken; // This won't work
     }
 }
```

Also

```
 function getToken()
{
    var ip=myip
    var mytoken;
    mytoken=saveData(ip); // This won't return any data
    alert(mytoken); // This won't give you anything useful

}
```

Comment: I have to assigned that value below the page to another javascript variable.thats why i want to return this..like this
sourceid = getToken();

Comment: Then you will have to assign `sourceid = newtoken;` inside the `success` handler. Note that `sourceid` should be global.

Answer (score 1):

Hi friends This is solution that for i was looking.

```
    function saveData(ip)
{

    return $JQ.ajax({

     type: "POST",

     url: "all_actions.php",

     data: 
     {
         page_url:document.URL,
         ip_address:ip 
     },
     async: false,

    }).responseText;
}
function getToken()
{
    var ip=myip
    var mytoken;
    mytoken=saveData(ip);
    return mytoken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 'A' in AJAX is 'Asynchronous'. Your alert is running before the AJAX request has had a chance to complete. You need to handle whatever you wish to do with the response inside of the `success: function()` or `.done()` functions of jQuery:

```
success: function(responce)
{
    if(responce)
    {
        var newtoken = responce;

        // Work here with newtoken...
    }
 }
```